# VBA Error 1004 Can't Find "File Name" When Trying To Open File

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open all Excel files (.xlsx) in a specified folder and extract information from each one to add to a master spreadsheet for a report.

I can't open the file. I get a

> Run-time error '1004'

saying it couldn't find FILE.xlsx.

The file name is correct and matches the file name and extension (.xlsx).

The last line of the code isn't working.

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim Folder As String
Dim Month As String
Dim File As Variant

Month = MonthName(CurrentMonth)
Folder = "C:\Users\mpresley\Documents\Other\Ben\Forecast Summary\Forecast"
FolderName = Folder & Month & CurrentYear

Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
Dim attachmentFolder As String, StrFile As String, filenameCriteria As String
Dim attachmentWorkBook As Workbook
Dim copyRngToArray As Variant

'# Set file extension
filenameCriteria = "xlsx"

'set
StrFile = Dir(FolderName & "\*" & filenameCriteria)
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set attachmentWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(StrFile)
```

Comment: You are missing path separators in the folder name and a "." in the file extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify both the folder path and the file name:

```
Set attachmentWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & "\" & StrFile)
```